# HTML Email - Not rendering correctly for Old Email Clients

Tags: html, email-client, electronic-direct-mail

I have at the start of the HTML Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org    
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=300, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /> <!-- disable auto telephone linking in iOS -->
<head>....
```

However, when it comes to old email clients, my HTML doesnt render at all, and is blank... I have tested this on litmus.

Is there something that I need to add or remove from above so that it also renders in the old browsers as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your meta tags should be inside the `<head>`.

What you have there otherwise looks fine, so it may have something to do with the rest of your document. I would recommend starting with [Sean Powell's email boilerplate](https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate/blob/master/email_lite.html) and bringing some of your code over.

Failing that, have you forgotten to close any elements such as tables/rows/cells?

Which email clients is it broken in?

Comment: Lotus Notes 6.5, Lotus Notes 7, Lotus Notes 8, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook.com(Firefox), Outlook.com(Chrome), Outlook.com(Internet Explorer). I have made the updates as per your requirement.